# VS Code Debug - Why Aren't Bash Commands Consistent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, visual-studio-code

I am writing python3 code in VS Code Version: 1.40.1 for macOS, and am using an anaconda virtual environment for the interpreter.

When I debug my code ("Debug>Start Debugging" or F5) the 1st time after opening the VS Code app, everything goes as expected, with the following bash commands being sent to VS Code internal terminal:

```
source /anaconda3/bin/activate

/anaconda3/envs/mvtrade/bin/python /Users/<user.name>/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.49689/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 56109 /Users/<user.name>/repos/mvtrade/scratch.py 

conda activate mvtrade

/anaconda3/envs/mvtrade/bin/python /Users/<user.name>/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.49689/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 56109 /Users/<user.name>/repos/mvtrade/scratch.py
```

All subsequent attempts to debug fail, with the following commands being sent to terminal:

```
/Users/<user.name>/repos/mvtrade ; env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 /anaconda3/envs/mvtrade/bin/python /Users/<user.name>/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.49689/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 57194 /Users/<user.name>/repos/mvtrade/scratch.py
```

Why are the commands so different between 1st and subsequent debug attempts?

Comment: Are you using the same `launch.json` debug configuration every time? And the activation is a one-time cost for the terminal we create for debugging and so it isn't done subsequently. So if the failure relates to imports failing then it's because the initial activation failed and the extension didn't try activating again.

Comment: @BrettCannon, I believe so. There is only one `launch.json` in my project. I haven't taken any deliberate action to modify that or any other file in to affect running or debugging my code.

Comment: Only other option is to open a bug report at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python

Comment: Will do, Thanks @BrettCannon!